# Method chaining in neo4jclient's return method

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I cannot figure out what the neo4jclient equivalent is for the following cypher query:

```
match (n)
return n.Property, n.AnotherProperty, n.head(label(n))
```

This is what I have so far:

```
.Match("n")
.Return((n) => new SomeNode
{
    Property = n.As<SomeNode>.Property,
    AnotherProperty = n.As<SomeNode>.AnotherProperty,
    Label = n.Labels() //This gives all labels, I only need the head. I can't chain it with ".head()"
}
```

I've looked around on stackoverflow as well as on the [wiki](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples) but I couldn't find any information on chaining functions.

Is there a way to achieve chaining in the way that I describe here, do I need to construct another query to get labels separately, then take the head of that list and add that to `SomeNode`, or am I missing a better, completely different approach?

I initially got here when I came across an error stating: 
"If you want to run client-side logic to reshape your data in .NET, use a Select call after the query has been executed, like .Return(…).Results.Select(r => …)."
Examples for this are, however, also not on the wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach that I can quickly think of is to use `Return.As` for any things like this you want to do in `Return`, so something like:

```
.Match("(n)")
.Return((n) => new SomeNode
{
    Property = n.As<SomeNode>.Property,
    AnotherProperty = n.As<SomeNode>.AnotherProperty,
    Label = Return.As<string>("head(labels(n))")
}
```

You *could* use a `With`:

```
.Match("(n)")
.With("n, head(labels(n)) AS firstLabel")
.Return((n, firstLabel) => new SomeNode
{
    Property = n.As<SomeNode>.Property,
    AnotherProperty = n.As<SomeNode>.AnotherProperty,
    Label = firstLabel.As<string>()
}
```

Much of a muchness between the two - you have to write the `head` bit as a `string` either way :/